# jquery select all elements except a div and its children

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, toggle, selector

I have this html/css code:

```
<body>
        <!-- BEGIN: HEADER AREA -->
        <?php require("snippets/header_area.php"); ?>
        <!-- END: HEADER AREA -->
        <div id = "presentation_area">
            <div id = "submenu_area">
                <div id = "sliding_menu_area">
                </div>
                <div id = "tags">
                    <div id = "1">
                        <img src = "lang/el/images/1.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div id = "2">
                        <img src = "lang/el/images/2.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div id = "3">
                        <img src = "lang/el/images/3.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div id = "4">
                        <img src = "lang/el/images/4.png" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

I am trying to trigger a function when the user clicks on everything else except for the `#sub_menu_area`. I use the following part of js:

```
$('*').not('#submenu_area').click(function(){
        if(slide == "open"){
            $('#sliding_menu_area').toggle(effect);
            slide = "close";
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately the children somehow are not excluded and on click it toggles a lot of times. Does anyone know how to do it properly?! :)

**EDIT:**
So what I need is a jquery selector to get properly: `on click of all elements of body EXCEPT for #submenu_area and its descendants`.

Comment: Could you operate the toggle on `$(this)`? Does that get at the heart of what you want done?

Comment: No because I want something like "all but this and its children". You have any working examples with `$(this)`?

Comment: Sorry; I possibly don't understand exactly what you're seeing and don't want to be happening. I realize more effects are getting toggled than you want but if you would create a jsfiddle.net, that would be helpful to display the behavior specifically. I thought you wanted to toggle on the thing that was clicked but it sounds like you're trying to see **no effect** on the 4 images since they're descendants of `submenu_area`, correct?

Comment: I want a selector to say:
`on click of all elements of body EXCEPT for #submenu_area and its descendants`
That's what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('#submenu_area, #submenu_area *')) {
            return;
        }
        if(slide == "open"){
            $('#sliding_menu_area').toggle(effect);
            slide = "close";
        }
    });
```

Comment: Way to go; this was quite the challenge. Glad you got your answer @Jonur

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
$('*').not("#submenu_area *").click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Isn't the square brackets only for attributes? I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work...

Comment: It would be `$('* :not(#submenu_area)')`, but this idea won't do what the OP wants anyway.

Comment: Woops, that is true (fixed). And why wouldn't this do what the OP wants?

Comment: This *only* excludes `#submenu_area`. It doesn't exclude any descendants ("children").

Comment: I want a selector to say: on click of all elements of body EXCEPT for #submenu_area and its descendants That's what I am trying to do. 

Also, what's an OP?!

Comment: @Jonur: Sorry, can't help any more right now, I'm working. An OP is... well, I'm not sure what an OP is, but it refers to the person who asked the question. :-)

Comment: @Jonur: [OP = Original Poster](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op). In other words, you.

Comment: Oh nice to know! :) But regarding my question, do you have any clue on what to do? No matter how much I google I cannot find a proper way to do it.

Comment: @Jonur, just thought of a way (I think). Updated my answer.

Comment: saved my day! (hour. but still...)