# select all but a div with its children with .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

yes i know this was ask before but i cant find the answer to my particluar problem.

this comes really close: [jquery select all elements except a div and its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552072/jquery-select-all-elements-except-a-div-and-its-children)

but i want to select all but the div with its children inside an .on() statement, like this (simplified)

```
$('body').on('click', ':not(._project_overlay), :not(._project_overlay *)', globalClickHandler);
```

I don't get why this wont works :-/
(I also tried every variant of the above)

something like this will indeed select everything but the div and all of its children:

```
$('body').find(':not(._project_overlay *)')
```

so why on earth binds .on() to the children of the div?

please help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), which is the equivalent of a logical `OR`:

```
:not(._project_overlay) OR :not(._project_overlay *)
```

Therefore, it ends up matching both `._project_overlay` and its descendants.

You want an `AND` instead, so you should simply write:

```
:not(._project_overlay):not(._project_overlay *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:not(._project_overlay, ._project_overlay *)` instead like following.

```
$('body').on('click', ':not(._project_overlay, ._project_overlay *)', globalClickHandler);
```